# No file found for: /<url-pattern>/

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

This seems like a very odd one, I have just created a new application (wineathome), and have borrowed a bunch of bits of old code from my other application (diarybooker).

It compiles fine, I have cleaned both projects, built both from scratch and even exited eclipse and rebooted the PC, but its still happening... I am getting an error (see below) telling me that there is "No file found for: /diarybooker/contact" which is obvious and I have removed ALL references to diarybooker from my wineathome application. I have even done a text search on all files, and there is nothing in there. Where is it picking this up from to be looking for it, and more importantly how can I stop this error?

Below the error message is the contents of my war/WEB-INF/web.xml file...

```
Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Successfully processed C:\eclipse\WineAtHome\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Successfully processed C:\eclipse\WineAtHome\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
[WARN] No file found for: /diarybooker/contact
[WARN] No file found for: /diarybooker/contact
[WARN] No file found for: /diarybooker/contact
[WARN] No file found for: /diarybooker/contact
[WARN] No file found for: /diarybooker/contact
[WARN] No file found for: /diarybooker/contact
[WARN] No file found for: /diarybooker/contact
```

**Web/WEB_INF/web.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ContactService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.wineathome.server.S_ContactServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ContactService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/wineathome/contact</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>WineAtHome.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `/diarybooker/contact` is being requested.  This could be caused by:

- A browser window open that is still trying to access that page
- A GWT module still called "diarybooker".  If your GWT module
  is still called that, then GWT will automatically prepend that to the
  `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` set in your `ContactService` class.  Be sure to check the `rename-to` attribute in your `<module>.gwt.xml` file.

Comment: Ahhh, yes I think the first option was the problem, I may well have had a Chrome tab trying to access the old app, which of course was no longer "running" closing everything down and rebooting didnt clear the problem because when I opened Chrome back up to try again, it loaded up all the same tabs again, including one that was trying to access /diarybooker/contact.  I have just been trying to fix a different problem, closed all tabs, so I only had gmail open, then when I restarted the local dev server, the error was no longer happening.

Comment: I came in here to let everyone know that the problem has gone away, and found your comment Jonathan and suddenly I realised what the problem had been. :D brilliant! Silly me!!